# Tcl - Удаление первого элемента списка

Tags: list, tcl

Например есть список

```
set s {1 2 3 4 5}
```

Как удалить 1, есть ли встроенная функция,
или надо делать свою ? ...

Answer (score 0):

```
set s {1 2 3 4 5}
set s [lreplace $s 0 0]
```

Это официальный способ удаления элемента из списка.